# Downgrade iOS 5.1 to iOS 5

Tags: xcode, ios5, downgrade, ios5.1

I'm a developer, and I have a little problem with iOS 5.1 upgrade.

So now, I want do "downgrade" iOS 5.1. I already downloaded the iOS 5 (9A334), and try to downgrade via Xcode, dragging the file to Xcode and restoring the iPad, but it's not working.

Any idea?

Comment: i had the same problem and found a fix here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649313/is-there-a-way-to-downgrade-from-ios-5-1-to-ios-5-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrades are normally not supported by Apple.

You can try to put your iPhone into recovery mode to restore to the older firmware.

Here are the instructions from Apple:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1808

As soon as your iTunes recognizes the iPhone to be in recovery mode, hold the ALT-Key and click on the restore button. It will prompt you to select the firmware you want to restore.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Plug your device into the PC.
2. While turned on, press and hold both power and home button for 10 seconds.
3. Release the power button after 10 seconds without releasing the home button and hold it until you see iTunes detecting your device in "recovery mode". Your device's screen should be completely black.
4. Press and hold shift if in Windows or Option if in Mac, and then click on "Restore" from iTunes
5. Browse for the desired firmware, and iTunes will start the restoration.

Comment: Thanks Fernando, but the _favo_ answered before. Thanks for the attention +1!

Comment: Np, always glad to help when I have remember of coming here! :)