# Is there a way to downgrade from iOS 5.1 to iOS 5.0?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I accidentally upgraded my iPhone 4 on 5.1 and now I can't test on Xcode 4.2 on my snow leopard. I don't want to upgrade to lion to download xcode 4.3 because I heart many people that said it slowed down their macs and had other several problems. Is there a way to downgrade from iOS 5.1 to iOS 5.0 and be able to test again my applications on xcode 4.2 on my snow leopard? I'd be grateful if someone helps thanks.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is a question pertaining to setting up a development environment to support a specific, common, programming situation, and as such is on topic as help with programming tools.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Xcode 4.2 can be made to work with iOS 5.1 devices.

Download Xcode 4.3 from [here](http://developer.apple.com/downloads). Copy the 5.1 SDK and Device Support folders from the 4.3 installer into your Xcode 4.2 folder.

The former goes into **Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs** and the latter into **Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport**

Comment: am on it now.. hope this works

Comment: not yet.. I just downloaded the new xcode now and am testing it now but i think it should work

Comment: @EricS basically i copied the whole platform folder from xcode 4.3 to xcode 4.2 but when i try to test it still says that xcode supports: ios 4.3, 5.0 (latest).. Any idea?

Comment: Did you quit and restart Xcode? I just copied the two folders from the installer to Xcode 4.2. The folder "5.1 (9B176)" goes into Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport and the folder "iPhoneOS5.1.sdk" goes into Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs. (I updated my original answer correcting the path slightly)

Comment: I copied both folders into xcode 4.2 but still it says the same thing. i quit and restarted it yeah but no luck..

Comment: @EricS Can you put every step in order? I tried everything .. Xcode still says it only supports: 4.3,5.0(latest)... Maybe I don't do something properly..

Comment: @AIK are you sure you're not just talking about the simulator? The simulator might only go up to 5.0. Still downloading...

Comment: Thanks, I've adapted, expanded and detailed this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9728951/8047 including how to get the Simulator and the Simulator with Retina working.

Answer (score 1):

If Apple is still signing 5.0 firmware installations (which is unlikely but worth a try) then user1116644's instructions will work.

Otherwise, the only way to downgrade from 5.1 is if you have an SHSH blob from one of the iOS 4 releases saved using TinyUmbrella. Then you can use that to install using the same procedure as user1116644 described, but using the TinyUmbrella TSS server to do the signing (more info here: http://thefirmwareumbrella.blogspot.com/)

Unfortunately Apple changed the way signing works for iOS 5 and SHSH blobs can no longer be used to downgrade to 5.x firmwares, only 4.3.x and below.

---

**Edit (4-30-12):** Actually since I posted this, it looks like a workaround has been developed to allow iOS 5.x downgrading as long as you saved your SHSH blob.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has been done signing iOS 5.0 for a while and just stopped signing iOS 5.0.1 either yesterday or the day before (I for sure know they are done though). So no you can't downgrade to any other version of iOS 5.

Answer (score -2):

Yes.

download the 5.0 firmware from felixbruns.de

put the device in DFU Mode

when you restore, hold shift and click restore a the same time.

select the firmware you downloaded

Comment: are u sure? This technique used to be working but I think apple are not allowing this anymore..