# Submitting a iOS 5.1 app to the App Store from a SL machine running Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

You may know that the last Xcode release for Snow Leopard was 4.2, with iOS 5 as the SDK.

I have seen other questions on here about how to run a app for 5.1 from a SL machine, but none about whether it is actually possible to develop a 5.1 iOS app and submit it to the app store with SL.

Has anyone tried this? Does it work?

Thanks!

Comment: You can install the 5.1 SDK into the Xcode 4.2 directory. I don't know if Apple will allow a submission that way. I suspect they will, but I haven't tried it yet. See my install instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649313/is-there-a-way-to-downgrade-from-ios-5-1-to-ios-5-0/9649396#9649396

Answer (score 1):

I just did a test run, and apps made in Xcode 4.2 run just fine on iOS 5.1. But, if your looking to work with the 5.1 SDK, that is only available in Xcode 4.3.

Comment: I think he was talking about using the 5.1 SDK, not just compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

While I've never done specifically what you're describing, I have submitted applications using beta Xcode versions (but public released iOS SDKs) and gotten approved.