# Am I able to still build and submit apps to the app store if I am only capable of running OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard with XCode 4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-leopard

Am I able to still build and submit apps to the app store if I am only capable of running OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard with XCode 4.2?  This limits me to iOS 5.0.1 development.

My Mac Mini maxes out at 10.6.8 and cannot run Lion, therefore it cannot run XCode 4.3 to develop for the iOS 5.1.x platform.

Should I continue to develop my app because it will be compatible or should I abandon my goal until I am able to upgrade my hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running 4.2 won't stop you from being able to upload your app to the App Store. Running this version will prevent you from being able to test your app against newer versions of iOS, leaving room for users to experience bugs that you didn't know existed.

Normally I'm an advocate of staying up to date, but considering there isn't an enormous difference between 5.0.1 and 5.1.1, you can probably pull it off. (at least for now) I would still recommend that you upgrade your hardware as soon as possible.

Comment: You can run Xcode 4.2 and test your app against iOS 5.x. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649313/is-there-a-way-to-downgrade-from-ios-5-1-to-ios-5-0/9649396#9649396 . Even without upgrading your SDK, you can do an adhoc build and test it on a real iOS 5.x device, although not under the debugger.